# layout with one columns, and increasing row number in java

Tags: java, layout

I need a layout in Java which contains only one column and number of rows are increasing during my app! (something like flowlayout but in vertical mode!)

Comment: Is this about HTML, Swing, Android?

Comment: We need more details in order to help. What graphics library are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **BoxLayout** and set its second parameter as **BoxLayout.Y_AXIS** to use **FlowLayout** in "vertical mode"

**Like this:**

```
panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
```

Does that answer your question?

Comment: how can I set gap between rows?